# Changing value of one variable in an object changes all other similar objects variable

Tags: c++, pointers, object

Not the best title so i'll change to explain myself better. I'm currently learning c++ and decided to try my hand at A* Path Finding. It finds the path no issue, but when setting the parent tiles for the FreeTile it set all the other FreeTile's parents to the same. So when i display all the parents they al shows as the same.

The Tiles are stored in an array as the base class Tile and are then cast to a FreeTile using a reference and converted back to a pointer. (Not sure if that's a bad way about it).

The Specific code causing this issue is below:

currentTile is a pointer towards the... current tile it was cast from a reference of a pointer in the array mapp.

setParent just changes the parent pointer in the object.

```
currentTile->setParent(tile);
currentTile->setF(calculateF(currentTile));
open.push_back(currentTile);
```

The Whole section is:

```
try{
    Tile* currentTileF = mapp[i+y][j+x];
    Tile& currentRef = *currentTileF;
    //cout<<"Trying to convert from Tile to FreeTile"<<endl;
    FreeTile& currentFRef = dynamic_cast<FreeTile&>(currentRef);
    currentTile = &currentFRef;
    free = true;
 }catch(bad_cast& bc){
    //cout<<"Bad Cast: "<<bc.what()<<endl;
    currentTileClosed = static_cast<ClosedTile*>(mapp[i+y][j+x]);
    free = false;
 }
 if(free){
     if(currentTile->getFree() && !inCloseList(currentTile)){
         if(!inOpenList(currentTile)){
             currentTile->setParent(tile);
             currentTile->setF(calculateF(currentTile));
             open.push_back(currentTile);
         }else{
             //cout<<"Already in open list"<<endl;
             if(currentTile->getCoordX()==tile->getCoordX() || currentTile->getCoordY()==tile->getCoordY()){
                 if((tile->getG() +10) < currentTile->getG()){
                     currentTile->setParent(tile);
                     currentTile->setF(calculateF(currentTile));
                     //cout<<"Updated Parent and F value for Horiz: "<<currentTile<<endl;
                 }
             }else{
                 if((tile->getG() +14) < currentTile->getG()){
                     currentTile->setParent(tile);
                     currentTile->setF(calculateF(currentTile));
                     //cout<<"Updated Parent and F value for Diag: "<<currentTile<<endl;
                 }
             }
         }
     }else{
         //cout<<"Either not free or in close list"<<endl;
 }
```

If i haven't explained anything clearly ill happily try and explain better :P

And as im new to c++ and never coded A* PF before it probably is badly written, so any advice generally will be well recieved :)

Thanks

Edit:

Test Code i made:

```
try{
    FreeTile& tempRef = dynamic_cast<FreeTile&>(*mapp[3][4]);
    FreeTile& tempRefP = dynamic_cast<FreeTile&>(*mapp[1][2]);
    FreeTile* temp = &tempRef;
    FreeTile* tempP = &tempRefP;
    temp->setParent(tempP);
}catch(bad_cast& bc){
}
```

This changes all the parents at once,though its only meant to change mapp[3][4]'s parent

Comment: Side note, considering that any advice is welcome... Instead of using plain arrays, please, consider using std::vector (or even std::array, if you will) for safety and overall ease of use. Also in the side of advice, I see you're casting your tiles here and there... You could create a struct that holds a reference to the tile and saves the state as open, close and such... As for your problem, will take a look. Can't guarantee anything as I suck at A* :(.

Comment: Im using namespace std so i assume its using std::array and ill have a look at structs, havent used any knowingly yet cheers :)

Comment: Yes... It is recommended though that you use std::vector... It's like an array but you get boundary checking, auto sizing, lots of operations, integration with algorithms from the std namespace and much, much more. Structs are just like classes actually, just everything is public by default. Suitable for small and temporary structures of data. Wild guess about the problem: are you sure all parents are not one and the same instance??

Comment: I checked and the parent is different every time, i did a test bit of code:
    try{
        FreeTile& tempRef = dynamic_cast<FreeTile&>(*mapp[3][4]);
        FreeTile& tempRefP = dynamic_cast<FreeTile&>(*mapp[1][2]);
        FreeTile* temp = &tempRef;
        FreeTile* tempP = &tempRefP;
        temp->setParent(tempP);
    }catch(bad_cast& bc){
    }
This changes all the parents at once,though its only meant to change mapp[3][4]'s parent... I've added the code example to the question to formatt it

Comment: You can just use `dynamic_cast` from a pointer to a pointer (and check for a null result) instead of your dance to references and back to pointers: `FreeTile* temp = dynamic_cast<FreeTile*>(mapp[3][4]);`

Comment: Oh cool, i couldnt work out how to check if it worked, thanks!

Comment: There must be something going on behind the scenes... Do you have access to any debugger (for example, nemiver on linux machines)?. Try and test a small set of tiles before and after you apply changes. Also, can you just do (mapp[3][4])->setParent(mapp[1][2])?. All the reference dancing is a bit confusing... Finally, let us take a look at the contents of setParent, maybe there's something there :).

Comment: Yeah i've dealt with all the referencing stuff. That is just a test bit btw, testing manually. And i'll look into a debugger, haven't used one before. The setParent function is simply just: `parent = tile` tile being the input to the method. But i've checked and its whenever setParent is called it changes all the instances, but if for example i call setG() which just changes a integer value it only changes it for the specific instance

Comment: Ok, Good News and Bad News. The good news is, problem is fixed and the advice you both gave me was highly appreciated and i will use :) the bad news, i'm an idiot and didnt declare the parent tile variable in the freetile header... sorry for wasting time with the main question! Thanks for the help, i'd vote you up if i could :) @The

Comment: Glad  you sorted it. Please, answer the question yourself so it is not left dangling without an answer. Perhaps it will foster even more comments worth looking at. C++ is a bit tricky to get the hang of - specially coming from other languages. Cheers.